# C# Winforms using TcpListener I can't connect to server from other devices on my LAN

Tags: c#, winforms, connection, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a Winforms application that's going to transfers data to an Android application, for now it accepts a connection and displays a line of text as output. I tested on my local machine using the telnet command in PowerShell and it returns the correct message. When I tried the command from another PC on my network, it just times out and fails to connect. I made sure the port was free and that my firewall was turned off.

Here is my method:

```
 public void senddata()
 {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                Int32 port = 4296;
                IPAddress localAddr =IPAddress.Any;
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
                server.Start();

                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

                while (true)
                {
                    server.Start();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    Debug.WriteLine("Connected!");
                    server.Stop();

                    while (stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) != 0)
                    {
                        string data = "CPU: " + cpuCircle.Value + " C" + "        |         GPU: " + gpuCircle.Value + " C";
                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }

                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException m)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("SocketException: "+m);
            }
            finally
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
        }).Start();
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Start from cmd.exe >Ping IP.  If IP doesn't work then try computer name.  You need both the route and return route.  So try Ping on both client and server to make sure it works in both directions.  If you are getting a timeout then there is no route.  If the port was already in use you would immediately get an exception.

Comment: I pinged both ways, both connected and transmitted data with 0% packet loss

Comment: If ping worked then only the port number being blocked would cause issue, except if you ping a different PC.  At work we often have two PCs configured with same IP.  So I usually pull the Ethernet cable out of one machine and try ping.  If I get a response then I know another PC has same IP address.I also use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which give list of all active port numbers and make sure when code is not running that the port number is not being used by another application.If Ping works then issue is with port number.Are you connected through any routers that may be blocking the port number?

Comment: Changed ports and tried, seemed to work for a bit then issue repeated itself with another device, for some reason the port was not being released after being used by the app which was being listed as listening in Netstat -a . I recreated my project since there wasn't alot of code yet and copied over the code exactly as it was with the same libraries, once i ran it again it terminated the connection correctly over the port and allowed other devices to connect, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You should only close from client and not server.  The close gets ACK and if you close at same time from both client and server one of the ACKs never completes leaving connection half open and half close.  Then you cannot connect because port is still open from last connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that your listener object is being created in Thread itself due to which only first client able to connect. Please make TcpListener object before calling senddata() method and this listener should accept connection before calling senddata() method as well and pass client object to senddata(TcpClient client) method. By doing so you would be able to entertain theoretically unlimited clients simultanously:

Try This:

```
void StackOverflow4() // Your calling method
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        Int32 port = 4296;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Any;
        try
        {
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            server.Start();

            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

            while (true)
            {                    
                Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                senddata(client);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException m)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SocketException: " + m);
            //Some logic to restart listner
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //Some logic to restart listner
        }
    }


    public void senddata(TcpClient client)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

           try
            {
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];

                while (true)
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    Debug.WriteLine("Connected!");
                    //server.Stop();

                    while (stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) != 0)
                    {
                        string data = "CPU: " + cpuCircle.Value + " C" + "        |         GPU: " + gpuCircle.Value + " C";
                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }

                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException m)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("SocketException: " + m);
            }
            finally
            {
                //server.Stop();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```